# Tor plug-in for Chromium?

Tags: socks, plugin, chrome

Is there a plug-in for Chromium to activate and deactivate Tor?

I've found plug-ins to manage HTTP proxies, but not SOCKS5.

Answer (score 8):

Currently the only safe web browser to use with Tor is Tor Browser. Tor Browser is based on Firefox but incorporates changes which are necessary to protect against profiling attacks. Many of the modifications which are needed are performed by the [Torbutton](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbutton.git) Firefox add-on but [other changes](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/tree/HEAD:/src/current-patches/firefox) have to be made at the code level.

It would be nice if Chrome was an available option, but it would be a large amount of work to audit and perform the necessary changes. It is not sufficient to just enable or disable a SOCKS proxy, but also to [remove all options](https://www.torproject.org/torbutton/en/design/) for fingerprinting users.

Privoxy and other HTTP proxies are not safe either because they only can remove fingerprinting information from HTTP traffic. It would be trivial for a malicious website to perform an attack to discover a user's identity by sending the attack traffic over HTTPS and so prevent the HTTP proxy from being able to detect the attempt.

Comment: There are many things that have to be considered when running a browser for anonymous web browsing. Tor project is aware of these and have prepared Tor Browser Bundle (TBB) accordingly. It is always best and safest to use TBB.

Answer (score 5):

[Proxy SwitchySharp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchysharp/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm/related?hl=en-US) supports SOCKS.

Here's an article on [How to browse the web anonymously with Google Chrome](http://xmodulo.com/2013/08/how-to-browse-web-anonymously-with-google-chrome.html) in Linux that covers configuration in detail.

*Note that there are some security holes when using this method to browse via Tor in Chrome, including but possibly/probably not limited to:*

- By default your DNS lookups will leak. 
  To avoid this you must uncheck “Predict network actions to improve page load performance” in Chrome Settings>Advanced. DNS lookups for anything other than HTTP/HTTPS will still leak.

Comment: Here's an article from the Tor Project themselves about [Google Chrome Incognito Mode, Tor, and Fingerprinting](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/google-chrome-incognito-mode-tor-and-fingerprinting).